# How to add star when clicked on vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My view is like this :

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    ...
    <star-rating :value="3"></star-rating>
    ...
</div>
```

My component star-rating is like this :

```
<template>
    <span class="rating">
        <template v-for="item in items">
            <label class="radio-inline input-star">
                <input type="radio" class="input-rating" name="input-rating" v-bind:value="item.value" @click="rate(item.value)">
            </label>
        </template>
    </span>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                items: [
                    {value: 5},
                    {value: 4},
                    {value: 3},
                    {value: 2},
                    {value: 1}
                ]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            rate: function (star) {
                this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl + '/star', {star: star}).then(function (response) {
                    console.log('submitted');
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the system executed, I want display star = 3 and when the star clicked, it display the star

I'm still confused when use vue.js

How can I do it?

Comment: As I know the `:value="3"` on star-rating component is the prop - I can't see into the star component props array anywhere ? `props: ['value']` ?
Also it would be nice if you could make jsfiddle or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add a star variable to your data  with a default value of 3 and then follow this example in the [vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio-1) on form input bindings.

It will be something like this:

```
<input v-for="item in items" type="radio" v-model="star" v-bind:value="item.value">
<span>Picked: {{ star }}</span> //for testing that the var changes.
```

Finally, you would want to send the star to your backend:

```
methods:{
        rate: function () {
        var star = this.star
            this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl + '/star', {star: star}).then(function (response) {
                console.log('submitted');
            });
        },
```